# Neo4j+PopotoJS: filter graph based-on predefined constraints

Tags: neo4j

I have a question about the query based on the predefined constraints in PopotoJs.  In this [example](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.popotojs.com%2Flive%2Fnode-images-filter%2Findex.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG-dBCrhtIEhwDBdagtoL2cLhkJ5w), the graph can be filtered based on the constraints defined in the search boxes. The sample file in [this](http://www.popotojs.com/release/examples.zip) example visualizations folder,  constraint is only defined for "Person" node. It is specified in the sample html file like the following:

```
"Person": {
        "returnAttributes": ["name", "born"],
        "constraintAttribute": "name",
        // Return a predefined constraint that can be edited in the page.
        "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
            return personPredefinedConstraints;
        },
        ....
```

In my graph I would like to apply that query function for more than one node. For example I have 2 nodes: Contact (has "name" attribute) and Delivery (has "address" attribute)
I succeeded it by defining two functions for each nodes. However, I also had to put two search box forms with different input id (like constraint1 and constraint2). And I had to make the queries in the associated search boxes.
Is there a way to make queries which are defined for multiple nodes in one search box? For example searching Contact-name and/or Delivery-adress in the same search box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I’d like to specify that the predefined constraints feature is still experimental (but fully functional) and doesn’t have any documentation yet.

It is intended to be used in configuration to filter data displayed in nodes and in the [example](http://www.popotojs.com/live/node-images-filter/index.html) the use of search boxes is just to show dynamically how it works.

A common use of this feature would be to add the list of predefined constraint you want in the configuration for every node types.

Let's take an [example](http://www.popotojs.com/live/node-images-filter/filtered-graph.html):

With the following configuration example the graph will be filtered to show only Person nodes having "born" attribute and only Movie nodes with title in the provided list:

```
"Person": {
    "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
        return ["has($identifier.born)"];
    },
    ...
}

"Movie": {
    "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
        return ["$identifier.title IN [\"The Matrix\", \"The Matrix Reloaded\", \"The Matrix Revolutions\"]"];
    },
    ...
}
```

The $identifier variable is then replaced during query generation with the corresponding node identifier. In this case the generated query would look like this:

```
MATCH (person:`Person`) WHERE has(person.born) RETURN person
```

In your case if I understood your question correctly you are trying to use this feature to implement a search box to filter the data. I'm still working on that feature but it won't be available soon :(

This is a workaround but maybe it could work in your use case, you could keep the search box value in a variable:

```
var value = d3.select("#constraint")[0][0].value;
inputValue = value;
```

Then use it in the predefined constraint of all the nodes type you want.
In this [example](http://www.popotojs.com/live/node-images-filter/input.html) Person will be filtered based on the name attribute and Movie on title:

```
"Person": {
    "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
        if (inputValue) {
            return ["$identifier.name =~ '(?i).*" + inputValue + ".*'"];
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    },
    ...
}

"Movie": {
    "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
        if (inputValue) {
            return ["$identifier.title =~ '(?i).*" + inputValue + ".*'"];
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Everything is in the HTML page of this [example](http://www.popotojs.com/live/node-images-filter/input.html) so you can view the full source directly on the page.

Answer (score 0):

@Popoto, thanks for the descriptive reply. I tried your suggestion and it worked pretty much well. With the actual codes, when I make a query it was showing only the queried node and make the other node amount zero. I wanted to make a query which queries only the related node while the number of other nodes are still same.

I tried a temporary solution for my problem. What I did is:

Export the all the node data to JSON file, search my query constraint in the exported JSONs, if the file is existing in JSON, then run the query in the related node; and if not, do nothing.

With that way, of course I needed to define many functions with different variable names (as much as the node amount). Anyhow, it is not a propoer way, bu it worked for now.